# Explain constexpr with const char*const

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants, constexpr

I have the following code:

```
static constexpr const char*const myString = "myString";
```

Could you please explain what is the difference from:

```
static const char*const myString = "myString";
```

What's new we have with constexpr in this case?

Comment: `const` = readonly. `constexpr` = constant. `const` objects can change, `constexpr` objects cannot. Top level `const` cannot change, but functions such as `strlen` cannot tell the difference between regular `const` and top level `const`, hence the need for `constexpr`.

Comment: isn't in the first example `static constexpr const char*const` is the same as `static constexpr const char* /*const*/`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609668/is-const-constexpr-on-variables-redundant

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference is described in the following quote from the C++ Standard (9.4.2 Static data members)

> 3 If a non-volatile **const static data member is of integral or
>   enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>   a brace-or-equal-initializer** in which every initializer-clause that
>   is an assignmentexpression is a constant expression (5.19). **A static
>   data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition
>   with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer** in which every initializer-clause that is
>   an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note
>   ] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   odr-used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall
>   not contain an initializer.

Consider for example two programs

```
struct A
{
    const static double x = 1.0;
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}

struct A
{
    constexpr static double x = 1.0;
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

The first one will not compile while the second one will compile.

The same is valid for pointers

This program

```
struct A
{
    static constexpr const char * myString = "myString";
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

will compile while this porgram

```
struct A
{
    static const char * const myString = "myString";
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

will not compile.

Comment: Could you, please, show an example of code to use `myString` which would be correct with one of declarations above and incorrect with the other?