# Is `const constexpr` on variables redundant?

Tags: c++, constexpr, equivalent

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) states that:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration or non-static
>   member function (until C++14) implies const.

---

Does "object declaration" mean "any variable declaration"?

I.e. is

```
constexpr const int someConstant = 3;
```

equivalent to

```
constexpr int someConstant = 3;
```

in C++11, C++14 and C++17?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) holds the answer and so much more so I am hesitant to use it as a dupe.

Comment: @NathanOliver I looked at that before, but didn't spot the part that answers my question because it's so far into the answer. That's the problem with large answers that answer multiple questions - sometimes it's hard to find the specific bit of information you're looking for.

Comment: It is in the section *When can I / should I use both, const and constexpr together? A. In object declarations.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In declarations with primitives, such as the one in your example, `const` is indeed redundant. However, there may be odd situations where `const` would be required, for example

```
constexpr int someConstant = 3;
constexpr const int *someConstantPointerToConstant = &someConstant;
```

Here, `someConstantPointerToConstant` is both a `constexpr` (i.e. it's known at compile time, hence `constexpr`) and it is also a pointer to constant (i.e. its object cannot be changed, hence `const`). The second declaration above would not compile with `const` omitted ([demo](https://ideone.com/0iv38Q)).

Comment: the pointer itself is still implicitly const, ie you dont have to write `constexpr const int * const` because its the same as `constexpr const int *`, right?

Comment: I think so - `const` is no needed since the pointer is made in-mutable by `constexpr` already which implies its constantness;

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number do you know what's the point of not making pointee implicitly `const` as well? We need to write `constexpr const char *`, which seems redundant and `constexpr char *` won't even compile...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number but only without `constexpr`. My question is why `constexpr` have not replaced `const` entirely in constant expression contexts. This would seem reasonable to me.

Comment: I’m quite puzzled by the existence and meaning of that pointer. First, `someConstant` is something that (only) lives at compile time, i.e. is used by the compiler’s C++ interpreter, may get inlined into some immediate values in instructions etc., but it is not a variable that could/should be pointed at. Second, how would such code cope with `-fPIC` where it cannot know (at compile time) the run-time address of that integer (plus there may never be such an address; as per my previous point).

Answer (score 7):

`const` is redundant in `const constexpr` for objects.

> Does "object declaration" mean "any variable declaration"?

It does.

As per [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object), a variable or a constant is an object:

> A variable is an object or a reference that is not a non-static data
>   member, that is introduced by a declaration.

Comment: I've upvoted, but I'm going to wait before accepting in case anyone can provide some citations, or better yet - quote the standard.

Comment: cppreference doesn't specify anywhere what it means by 'an object declaration'.

Comment: @Pharap It does define [object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

Comment: On a different page to what I linked to, hence I did not cite that, and until that last comment neither had you.

Comment: @Pharap You said that it does not specify **anywhere**, this was the reason for my reply.